# change or alternative for system beep?

Tags: c++, audio, beep

I'm playing around with it in C++ and I'd like to make something similiar to a synthesizer, of course not so complex and accurate. With the system beep there are some funny results, but I'd like to know if theres a way to change the system beep some way (e.g. the waveform) or if there is some kind of library which one can use to output sound like this.

Comment: On what platform? And for only your program or for the whole system?

Comment: Windows 7. I just want it for my program

Answer (score 0):

The waveform is a square wave, and I do not think it can be changed (there is a brief doc on it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker)).

I have attached a simple beep program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>   // WinApi header file
int main()
{
  Beep(523,500);  // 523 hertz (C5) for 500 milliseconds
  Beep(587,500);
  Beep(659,500);
  Beep(698,500);
  Beep(784,500);
  Sleep(500);    // 500 ms delay
  return 0;
}
```

and here are the frequencies (from trial and error) for various notes:

```
Do  0: 261,626  Do  1: 523,251  Do  2: 1046,502
Do# 0: 277,183  Do# 1: 554,365  Do# 2: 1108,731
Re  0: 293,665  Re  1: 587,33   Re  2: 1174,659
Re# 0: 311,127  Re# 1: 622,254  Re# 2: 1244,508
Mi  0: 329,628  Mi  1: 659,255  Mi  2: 1318,51
Fa  0: 349,228  Fa  1: 698,456  Fa  2: 1396,913
Fa# 0: 369,994  Fa# 1: 739,989  Fa# 2: 1479,978
So  0: 391,995  So  1: 783,991  So  2: 1567,982
So #0: 415,305  So #1: 830,609  So #2: 1661,219
La  0: 440      La  1: 880      La  2: 1760
La# 0: 466,164  La# 1: 932,328  La# 2: 1864,655
Si  0: 493,883  Si  1: 987,767  Si  2: 1975,533
```

I have an old program at home that plays star wars music via the speaker, and will upload it tonight.

Hope this helps some:)  Let me know if you need any more information.

PS when I started programming this was a legitimate way of providing sound for games!